# Mark only one internal class as visible to other assemblies

Tags: c#, .net, compilation, .net-assembly, solution

I know the existance of the [InternalsVisibleTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) Attribute, which make all the internal classes visible to external assemblies.

In my case I have an **Utilities** project where all the classes should be visible to only **one specific assembly**.
All but one class, which contains Extension methods that should be visible to all the other assemblies in the solution and not to the external projects.

Which is the best way to achieve this result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, one way to achieve this, if you are using an IDE capable of this, is to share the file with the class with the Extension methods. This way if you mark it as internal, and all other classes as public, then you can have access to the extension methods, but it is not public. Also, when you edit the extension method class, this will be reflected in all of your assemblies in your solution. In Visual studio, the way to achieve this is to right click  your project and select Add -> Add Existing item:

[image]

And then find your file and select Add as link:

[image]

Please note that friend assemblies should be used mostly for debugging and testing purposes. Using them as a feature is a code smell.

Comment: Really? Code smell? Maybe I have misunderstood the purpose of friend assembly. What I want is to share my code only to the other assemblies of the solution. I want to block someone else, from another project, to just grab my code and use it for his work.

Comment: @simoneL The reason that it is a code smell, is that there are already some constructs for visibility. If you need to provide some service, then it should be public. If not, then it should be internal.

Comment: @simoneL If you need to limit access to provided services, then use interfaces, some public and some internal and have your classes implement these interfaces while your classes are internal. When a reference of that class is required by an outside assembly force the sue of a factory and return as one of the interfaces.

Comment: And if I want to completely hide my classes to external assemblies, what I should do?

Comment: @simoneL Look, if you want to have them accessible but only within your own assemblies, then by all means, use InternalsVisibleTo! The fact that it is a code smell, does not mean that it must not be used. What it does mean is that you should consider the use carefully and consider other solutions if they exist. Again, public and internal exist for a reason...

Comment: @simoneL By the way, my solution (with shared files) solves your question exactly and it is a practice widely used in Xamarin solutions. Please consider marking my answer as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Split them up. Put the common class in its own assembly.

There is no way to specify specific classes as being "internals visible to".

Comment: Maybe I was not enough clear in my question. None of the classes in the Utils project is public, they are all internals. The difference is that all of them should be used in just another assembly of the solution, but the Extensions class which should be available in all the remaining assemblies but not in the external ones.

Comment: I'll rephrase my answer, and change "public" to "common". The rest of the answer stays the same...